# Gaelyk eclipse configuration error

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gaelyk

I've tried to configure a gaelyk project in eclipse using the gradle script of the template project and always failed.
to do this I use the following command:
gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse

All the packeges seems correctly downloaded, the .project and .classpath files are created but I always fint this error on the project:

```
The App Engine SDK 'C:\Users\username\.gradle\caches\artifacts\com.google.appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\c12498cf18507aa6433a94eb7d3e77d5\jars\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.6.1.jar' on the project's build path is not valid
(SDK location 'C:\Users\username\.gradle\caches\artifacts\com.google.appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\c12498cf18507aa6433a94eb7d3e77d5\jars\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.6.1.jar' is not a directory)
```

It seems that the appengine SDK is specified uncorrectly in the .classpath/.project files.
I've installed eclipse Indigo and the last version of the google plugin for eclipse

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you mean `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse`. What Google plugin? In case you mean the STS Gradle plugin, that's an _alternative_ to `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse`.

Comment: yup! the command is that one: I'm editing the question for clarity. the plugin is the google plugin for eclipse: http://code.google.com/eclipse/

Comment: I suggest to ask the Gaelyk devs. Not sure if the Eclipse project generated by the Gradle build is meant to be used together with the Google plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am personally not using Eclipse for Gaelyk development. Therefore, I am not sure if the existing Eclipse configuration in the Gradle build script of the template project will work with the Google plugin.

However, a while ago I got a [pull request](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-gae-plugin/pull/9) for the Gradle GAE plugin to integrate with the Eclipse plugin. I had turned it down because it's too specific and it would lead to potentially a lot of bugs to the Gradle plugin as the Google configuration might change. The [author](https://github.com/johnedc) was planning to creating a separate plugin for it so you can try to ping him.

I also know of another [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-gaelyk-eclipse-plugin) that might help you here. Also try to post your question the [Gaelyk mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/gaelyk).